# firefox print css issue

Tags: css

On firefox I want to hide the top right corner content in my pdf but it seems 
not working at all.

I only need

Page # of # in the left bottom section and I don't need anything else on any corner of the pdf.

The Code

```
/* firefox print css */
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 

   @top-right 
      {
        display: none;
      }
}
```

Comment: Use the Chrome/Firefox developer console to debug.

Comment: @top-right this is not a valid css selector, maybe with point(class) or "#" (id).

Comment: @DincaAdrian  please share any example.

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen Thank for suggestions.